# Can not install VLC Media Player on Fedora 34

Tags: linux, fedora, vlc

when i try to install VLC  `# dnf install vlc` ,   i get these Errors:

```
Error: 

Problem: package vlc-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64 requires vlc-core(x86-64) = 1:3.0.16-1.fc34, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package vlc-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64 requires libvlccore.so.9()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides live555(x86-64) = 2020.07.31 needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  - nothing provides libx264.so.161()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  - nothing provides libx265.so.199()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  - nothing provides libfaad.so.2()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  - nothing provides libdca.so.0()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64  
  - nothing provides libBasicUsageEnvironment.so.1()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  - nothing provides libUsageEnvironment.so.3()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  - nothing provides libgroupsock.so.8()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  - nothing provides libliveMedia.so.79()(64bit) needed by vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

I don't understand why it says **conflicting requests**

Then i tried to install the dependencies manualy:

`# dnf deplist vlc`

and got:

```
package: vlc-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: /bin/sh
   provider: bash-5.1.0-2.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: /usr/bin/sh
   provider: bash-5.1.0-2.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: dejavu-sans-fonts
   provider: dejavu-sans-fonts-2.37-16.fc34.noarch
  dependency: dejavu-sans-mono-fonts
   provider: dejavu-sans-mono-fonts-2.37-16.fc34.noarch
  dependency: dejavu-serif-fonts
   provider: dejavu-serif-fonts-2.37-16.fc34.noarch
  dependency: hicolor-icon-theme
   provider: hicolor-icon-theme-0.17-10.fc34.noarch
  dependency: libQt5Core.so.5()(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtbase-5.15.2-16.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Core.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtbase-5.15.2-16.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Core.so.5(Qt_5.15)(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtbase-5.15.2-16.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Gui.so.5()(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.15.2-16.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Gui.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.15.2-16.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Svg.so.5()(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtsvg-5.15.2-4.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Svg.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtsvg-5.15.2-4.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Widgets.so.5()(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.15.2-16.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5Widgets.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.15.2-16.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5X11Extras.so.5()(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtx11extras-5.15.2-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libQt5X11Extras.so.5(Qt_5)(64bit)
   provider: qt5-qtx11extras-5.15.2-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libX11.so.6()(64bit)
   provider: libX11-1.7.2-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libXext.so.6()(64bit)
   provider: libXext-1.3.4-6.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libXinerama.so.1()(64bit)
   provider: libXinerama-1.1.4-8.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libXpm.so.4()(64bit)
   provider: libXpm-3.5.13-5.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libfluidsynth.so.2()(64bit)
   provider: fluidsynth-libs-2.1.8-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libfreetype.so.6()(64bit)
   provider: freetype-2.10.4-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libfribidi.so.0()(64bit)
   provider: fribidi-1.0.10-4.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit)
   provider: libgcc-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0)(64bit)
   provider: libgcc-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.3.1)(64bit)
   provider: libgcc-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libjack.so.0()(64bit)
   provider: jack-audio-connection-kit-1.9.17-1.fc34.x86_64
   provider: pipewire-jack-audio-connection-kit-0.3.33-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libm.so.6()(64bit)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.29)(64bit)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libpthread.so.0()(64bit)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libpulse.so.0()(64bit)
   provider: pulseaudio-libs-14.2-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libpulse.so.0(PULSE_0)(64bit)
   provider: pulseaudio-libs-14.2-3.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6()(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.29)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)(64bit)
   provider: libstdc++-11.2.1-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libvlccore.so.9()(64bit)
   provider: vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: libwayland-client.so.0()(64bit)
   provider: libwayland-client-1.19.0-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: rtld(GNU_HASH)
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.i686
   provider: glibc-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: vlc-core(x86-64) = 1:3.0.16-1.fc34
   provider: vlc-core-1:3.0.16-1.fc34.x86_64
  dependency: xdg-utils
   provider: xdg-utils-1.1.3-9.fc34.noarch
```

I installed every single of them but still getting the first Error.

(I tried to install VLC on another Fedora 34 and did'nt get these Errors and it was installed successfully and working whithout any problem.)

Does anyone know why??

Comment: ← https://superuser.com/questions/1669465/can-not-install-vlc-media-player-on-fedora-34 ... "
Installing vlc-core-3.0.16-1 will downgrade three packages. ... If you previously installed a package / other packages depending on {libaom, libavif, libvmaf}, then vlc cannot be installed. ......... Rpmfusion is not as compatible with Fedora, as it used to be years back. "

Comment: @KnudLarsen what can i do? should i remove these three packages? doesn't this cause problems?

Comment: https://rpmfusion.org/ReportingBugs